# genfromtxt() Save results to separate file

Tags: numpy

I am new to python and I have question regarding genfromtxt(). I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
Myfile = "C:\\Users\\suntzu\\Desktop\\winequality-red.csv"
ds = np.genfromtxt(Myfile,names=True, delimiter=',')
```

I am trying to redirect this output to a new file. I searched on google for sometime and I can seem to figure out on how to do this.

Comment: Use `pandas.read_csv()` function read the file. Then if want to save the data as numpy array use `numpy.save('file.npy', data)`.

Comment: `genfromtxt` produces a `numpy` array.  That's not text which can be 'redirected' to a file.  There are ways of `saving` an array to a file.  But before that, you need to understand what `ds` is, its properties like `shape` and `dtype`.  Learn some basics of `numpy` before trying to do something 'big'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:
To save as csv using numpy , Try this:

```
np.savetxt("save.csv",ds, delimiter=",")
```

To save as numpy file, try this :

```
np.save("save.npy",ds)
```